# zend paginator with random sorting

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

Is it possible to use zend paginator on a mysql query with random ordering?

I'm struggling to wrap my head around this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ORDER BY RAND() will (unsuprisingly) return random results each time it is run, so you won't be able to paginate this in the normal way.

You would have to select ALL the data in the first run, record the order of the elements and use this on any subsequent pages. Alternatively you could just select all the data and do the pagination with Ajax. Either approach would be a fair bit of work.

Comment: thanks, thought there might be some kind of caching feature that i could paginate through.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with mysql rand(n) function.

"n is used as the seed value, which produces a repeatable sequence of column values"

So simply add to your select - for example


`SELECT
    rand(21) AS ord
FROM
    TABLE
ORDER BY
    ord`

and every time you wand different set of results, just change 21 to something else.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ORDER BY RAND({seed})`, as explained [here](http://blog.motane.lu/2012/01/10/paginating-randomly-ordered-sql-results-with-zend_paginate/) (with zend integration).